# frequency table for dice c# console

Tags: c#, random

Hello I am trying to create a frequency table for a dice rolling game. Here are the instructions for the project that i am working on :

Create an application that simulates rolling a standard 6-sided die (numbered 1 – 6).

- The die should be rolled exactly 10,000 times.
- The 10,000 rolls should be an input by the user; Ask them how often they want to roll the dice
- The values of the rolled dice should be determined using a random value, based upon the outputs of the Random class object (see notes below).
- After the program completes rolling the number of times the user requested (10,000), the application should present a table displaying the number of times each dice was rolled.
- The program should ask the user if they would like to simulate another session of rolling the die.  Keep track of the number of sessions.

Now I know how to use the random number class but I am stuck on the summary table part of the project and I just need something that can help me get started

here is where I am so far in the project and as you will see my summary table makes no sense:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

namespace Dice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rndGen = new Random();

            Console.WriteLine("welcome to the ralph dice game");
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("how many times do you want to roll");
            int rollDice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < rollDice; i++)
            {
                int diceRoll = 0;

                diceRoll = rndGen.Next(1,7);

                string table = " \tfrequency\tpercent";
                table +="\n"+ "\t" + i + "\t" + diceRoll;

                Console.WriteLine(table);

            }//end for

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> present a table displaying the number of times each dice was rolled.

If I understand this correctly, it means how many times the dice get 1, 2, 3, etc... You need an array to store all the outcome counts, and output when all rolls are done.

*Note: untested code.*

```
int[] outcomes = new int[6];

// init
for (int i = 0; i < outcomes.Length; ++i) {
    outcomes[i] = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < rollDice; i++)
{
    int diceRoll = 0;

    diceRoll = rndGen.Next(1,7);

    outcomes[diceRoll - 1]++; //increment frequency. 
    // Note that as arrays are zero-based, the " - 1" part turns the output range 
    // from 1-6 to 0-5, fitting into the array.

}//end for

// print the outcome values, as a table
```

> Keep track of the number of sessions.

Just use another variable, but you code apparently does not seem to have this part implemented. A simple way is to use a do-while loop:

```
do {

    // your code

    // ask if user wish to continue

    bool answer = // if user want to continue

} while (!answer);
```

Comment: that really helped me out but i'm still stuck at how to call those numbers from the dice roll that is in the array and put them in a table.

Comment: Use a for-loop to read through the array. `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) { Console.WriteLine(array[i]); }`